# "Sterben" oder "versterben"?

Tags: word-choice

In Reich-Ranickis *Für alle Fragen offen* lese ich, dass Nabokov "1977 verstarb".
Ist das ein respektvoller Ausdruck für "starb", oder liegt da eine andere Nuance  vor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spiegel "versterben" is more formal and graceful. (See http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-verstorben-gestorben-a-344430.html)

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Tobias.

In reverse order of Formality:

Verrecken

Abkratzen

Den Geist aufgeben.

Sterben

Versterben

Verscheiden